# showing exception for imageview

Tags: android

i have an android application which has an imageview object in main thread. i called a method fron another thread to set the bitmap of imageview. it shows an exception "calledFromWrongthreadException" 
anybody please help with some hints

Answer (score 0):

You have to run this method on your UI thread, e.g. via a [`Handler`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Handler.html). The absolutely best way is to create and execute an [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) and run the method in `onPostExecute()`. A good introduction can be found here: http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2009/05/painless-threading.html